# Kendo UI grid filter with text and value dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on updating the Kendo UI grid custom filter with using dropdownlist and combobox for 2 columns. I followed the demo on telerik and was able to display the **Text** value in the dropdownlist. However the column is actually based on the **Value**, for example the following facility has **Text** LAX03S and **Value** 15.

I have the following code in controller returns the list of facilities:

```
public ActionResult GetFacilitySelection()
{
    var allFacilities = _facilityService.GetAllFacilities();
    var selection = allFacilities.Select(m => new { Text = m.NetworkCode, Value = m.Id }).OrderBy(m => m.Text).ToList();

    return Json(selection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the following is the view that contains the grid and script:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OutboundCustomBatchConfigurationViewModel>()
    .Name("ConfigGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.SorterName).ClientTemplate("#=Sorter#").Title("Sorter");
        columns.Bound(m => m.FacilityId).Width(200).ClientTemplate("#=NetworkCode#").Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("FacilityFilter"));
        columns.Bound(m => m.DefaultCnPPort).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(m => m.DefaultCnEPort).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(m => m.ShipperId).ClientTemplate("#=ShipperName#").Width(200).Title("Shipper").Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("ShipperFilter"));
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(100);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .ToolBar(tb =>
    {
        tb.Create().Text("Add Configuration");
    })
    .DataSource(ds =>
    {
        ds.Ajax()
        .Read("ReadCustomBatchConfiguration", "OutboundSorting")
        .Create("UpsertCustomBatchConfiguration", "OutboundSorting")
        .Update("UpsertCustomBatchConfiguration", "OutboundSorting")
        .Model(md => { md.Id(m => m.Id); })
        .Events(e => e.Error("function(args){onGridBoundError(args,\"ConfigGrid\");}"));
    }) 
    .Filterable(ft => { ft.Enabled(true); })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("MappingTemplate")
)

<script>
    function FacilityFilter(element) {
        element.kendoComboBox({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("GetFacilitySelection")"
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

If I update the GetFacilitySelection to return only the string list of NetworkCode, the dropdownlist will display the NetworkCodes successfully but sorting will fail(like I mentioned above, the sorting is based on the value). So I think I need to make some change in the script but not sure how to do it. Can i get some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, also accidental typo in the question, should be kendoDropDownList instead of KendoComboBox. Added dataTextField and dataValueFi

```
function FacilityFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "@Url.Action("GetFacilitySelection")"
            }
        }
    });
}
```